# Google Cloud metrics

Tags: docker, logging, google-compute-engine

I'm running some servers with a docker container.

Recently I've seen that disk space on my root disk (inside docker) is getting low. That disk is "mapped" as /mnt/stateful_partition in the physical machine.

I've searched for big files in the physical disk and I've found one that puzzles me:

```
/mnt/stateful_partition/var/lib/metrics/uma-events
```

That file keeps growing evey day (roughly 5 MB a day) and it's eating up all my disk space.

One of my server was created back in october 2019. Now that file (uma-events) is 3.558.914.410 bytes and is written in a partition that is roughly 7 GB... and I've only 800 MB left. At 5 MB/day it's gonna be full in about 5 month... :-|

The file contains something like this:

```
1linearhistogramPlatform.Crouton.Started 0 28histogramPlatform.ReadSectorsLong 6843 1 500000 50:histogramPlatform.W
riteSectorsLong 83484 1 500000 504histogramPlatform.PageFaultsLong 21 1 62500 508histogramPlatform.PageFaultsFileLo
ng 21 1 62500 507histogramPlatform.PageFaultsAnonLong 0 1 62500 50/histogramPlatform.SwapInLong 0 1 62500 500histog
ramPlatform.SwapOutLong 0 1 62500 503linearhistogramPlatform.MeminfoMemFree 75 1002linearhistogramPlatform.MeminfoB
uffers 0 1002linearhistogramPlatform.MeminfoCached 16 1001linearhistogramPlatform.MeminfoActive 4 1004linearhistogr
amPlatform.MeminfoInactive 15 100:histogramPlatform.MeminfoUnevictable 0 1 4000000 1004linearhistogramPlatform.Memi
nfoAnonPages 3 1001linearhistogramPlatform.MeminfoMapped 1 ...
```

What is it uma-events? Is there a way of enabling an automatic rolling or something? Can I switch it off?